# Merging data frame based on if-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following two data frames df1 and df2

```
  type num1  dem
   t1   m1   32
   t1   m2   33
   t2   p1   34
   t2   p2   35

and

  type  num1  num2
   t1    -     23
   t1    -     24
   t2    n1    25
   t2    n2    26
```

I want to merge these two data frames based on two different rules. In `df2`, if `df2['num1']` is empty then I will operate merge operation based on only type. If `df2['num1']` is non-empty, then I'll concatenate `type` and `num1` column for both the data frame and then will do the merge operation based on this new column.

Initially my thought was that, I would create an extra column, called `flag` for both the data frames and then will separate these two data frames and do the operation separately. At the end, will do `pd.concat` to join these two data frames.

I did it,

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2[d2['num1'].isna()], on = 'type', how = 'left')
```

But it is not giving me proper answer. I think I am missing something.

Kindly help.

Comment: What is your expectd output?

Answer (score 1):

If I get your rules properly, then you should do it this way

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the first data frame
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['t1', 't1', 't2', 't2'],
    'num1': ['m1', 'm2', 'p1', 'p2'],
    'dem': [32, 33, 34, 35]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['t1', 't1', 't2', 't2'],
    'num1': ['', '', 'n1', 'n2'],
    'num2': [23, 24, 25, 26]
})

def merge_key(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['num1']):
        return row['type']
    else:
        return row['type'] + row['num1']

df1['merge_key'] = df1.apply(merge_key, axis=1)
df2['merge_key'] = df2.apply(merge_key, axis=1)

df2_empty = df2[df2['num1'] == '']
df2_nonempty = df2[df2['num1'] != '']
merged_empty = pd.merge(df1, df2_empty[['type', 'num2']], on='type', how='left')
merged_nonempty = pd.merge(df1, df2_nonempty[['merge_key', 'num2']], on='merge_key', how='left')

merged = pd.concat([merged_empty, merged_nonempty], ignore_index=True)
merged['num2'] = merged['num2'].fillna(0)

print(merged)
```

which returns

```
  type num1  dem merge_key  num2
0   t1   m1   32      t1m1  23.0
1   t1   m1   32      t1m1  24.0
2   t1   m2   33      t1m2  23.0
3   t1   m2   33      t1m2  24.0
4   t2   p1   34      t2p1   0.0
5   t2   p2   35      t2p2   0.0
6   t1   m1   32      t1m1   0.0
7   t1   m2   33      t1m2   0.0
8   t2   p1   34      t2p1   0.0
9   t2   p2   35      t2p2   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `concat` idea was the correct one. Split `df2` in two with a mask and handle both cases separately:

```
# condition to split df2
# this could be df2['num1'].eq('-')
# if dashes are used
m = df2['num1'].isna()

# merge separately and combine
out = pd.concat([
  df1.merge(df2[~m], on=['type', 'num1']),
  df1.merge(df2[m].drop(columns=['num1']), on=['type'])],
  ignore_index=True
 )

print(out)
```

Output (with a sightly different `df1` as input):

```
  type num1  dem  num2
0   t2   p1   34    25
1   t1   m1   32    23
2   t1   m1   32    24
3   t1   m2   33    23
4   t1   m2   33    24
```

Used input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['t1', 't1', 't2', 't2'],
    'num1': ['m1', 'm2', 'p1', 'p2'],
    'dem': [32, 33, 34, 35]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'type': ['t1', 't1', 't2', 't2'],
    'num1': [np.nan, np.nan, 'p1', 'n2'],
    'num2': [23, 24, 25, 26]
})
```